# scroll div on ipad

Tags: ipad, scroll

I want to scroll a small div on the page, but when I use a ipad, it scrolls the full page. On a PC, I can click the scroll bar, it works well. I have used the property `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` as the others suggested, but it didn't work. Does anyone have a good solution?

Comment: Have you got any link or code?

Comment: <div style = "height: 400px; overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; overflow-y: scroll;" > This is the property of the div,and in the div there is a table.when I click the link of the div,I hope to show the table , and the div can be scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your  section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

That makes sure that the page stays in place and doesn't scroll when you only want to scroll a part that has an overflow. A good example where this is useful is when you want to create a map, and zoom with pinch. You only want to zoom the map, not the page around it, which would be the default behaviour.

Comment: OK,I will have a try.Thank you.

Comment: NO,it didn't work,the full page scrolled again.Imagine that I have a home page , the link of the small div is on it,when I click the link,the div appears above the home page.Then I want to know the content which at the bottom of the div , so I need to scroll the bar,but on a ipad , it scrolls the full home page.I'm afraid if there was a bug on the ipad?